# How do I perform batch upsert in Spring JDBC?

Tags: spring-data, jdbctemplate

I have list of records, I want to perform following tasks using SpringJDBCTemplate
(1) Update existing records
(2) Insert new records.

Don't know how this happens using jdbcTemplate of spring.
Any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use one of the various forms of `batchUpdate` for the update. Then you check the return value which will contain 1 if the row was present and 0 otherwise. For the later, you perform another `batchUpdate` with the insert statements.

Comment: But this won't work in Oracle 11G (or lower version) or using Ojdbc6 (or lower version) as connection jar.